# $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/4} (\tan x)^n dx,n\ge2$ recurrence

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/4} (\tan x)^n dx,n\ge2$$

Show that $I_n+I_{n+2}=\frac{1}{n+1}$. Can somebody help me, please? I got that $I_n+I_{n+2}=1-n\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{(\tan x)^n}{cos^2x}dx$ but it's not working this way.

Comment: I suggest including more of your work, so that it's easier for someone to point out where you went awry.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$I_n+I_{n+2}=\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{n}x\,(1+\tan^2x)\,\mathrm d x$$
Now, remember that $\;\tan'(x)=1+\tan^2x$, so proceed by substitution and set $t=\tan x$.

*Some details*:
If we set $t=\tan x$, we have $\;\mathrm d t=(1+\tan^2x)\,\mathrm dx$ and, for the bounds, $x=0\longleftrightarrow  0$, $\; x=\frac\pi 4\longleftrightarrow t=1$, so
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{n}x\,(1+\tan^2x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^1t^n\,\mathrm dt=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\Biggm\vert_0^1$$

Comment: I tried that and you'll go in a loop.

Comment: I think we need another strategy

Comment: No, it works fine, but there was a typo: I wrote $n-2$ instead of $n+2$, so my $n-2$ was your $n$. It's  fixed now.  Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: I've written it down. It's not working

Comment: @Gaboru: you didn't use the useful formula for the derivative of the tangent (there are two formulæ!). Please see my edit

Answer (score -1):

$I_n+I_{n+2}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}(\tan x)'(\tan x)^n\,dx=1-n\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}(\tan x)^n\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\ $